# Whence the -s- in "Stöpsel"

Tags: etymology

The usual sources only say that "Stöpsel" was from "Low German", akin to "stop". I was wondering about the suffix.

The question arose wondering whether En "stop" is cognate, but it is interesting to me because of the several alternatives I have in mind:

- The word is a doublette of "Stopfen", in which the *f* seems to be from the second consonant shift, in which Low German "Appel" did not participate; The *s* is probably not from *f*. Alas, I have no older material at hand to compare, and so, as the Original root is linked to PIE *stew- (cp e.g. "Stau") I wonder whether labial *w* was completely lost. A *Stopfen* is also something woven to fix holes in clothes, hence *Stoff* "textile" seems close.
- - That is a very unlikely avenue, in my book. *w* did not regularly fricate, nor was it subject to metathesis (wp > pw?), nor did *f* regularly become *f* in any case, that I know of.
- *-l* also appears like a diminutive suffix, e.g. in "Madl" (Mädchen, Magd), "Bübele", that is popular in Bavarian, in Yiddish, but perhaps also Saxon, or anywhere.
- - This does not explain the *s*. I wonder also whether *stub, stubbble*, *Stumpf, Stoppel* belong here or below:
- *-l* alpears as instrumental suffix in *needle, paddle*, and involved *-th, thus its deemed an explanation of the illusive *threshold. German *s* and *z* are allophone in Ablaut due to Auslautverhärtung, and *z* generally corresponds to *t (Zahn ~ tooth). *pt* is generally not phonemic in German, but cp eg "Klapptisch".
- - Nothing fits together in this one. The documentation in wiktionary isn't great ([[threshold]] still shows a redlink for the suffix), and my memory is even worse.

Since this is all very messy, I'd appreciate anyone who can give me a clearer picture.

Comment: It's basically a diminutive.

Comment: *Bübele* doesn’t sound Bavarian at all. Maybe Swabian or Franconian.

Comment: @Jan, ah yes, that would be the *Bub'*

Comment: Now that we can know it comes from the "-sel" derivation, the more interesting question is: why did it become maskuline, when all other "-sel" words (that I know of) are neuter?

Comment: @phipsgabler According to Duden, "Streusel" can be masculine or neuter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The suffix is ["-sel"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_words_suffixed_with_-sel), which according
to [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS25767#XGS25767) is a variant of ["-sal"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_words_suffixed_with_-sal).
The German suffix "-sel" forms nouns from verbs,
it is a cognate of Old English "-else" and Swedish "-else" [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-sel#German) and derived from Proto-Germanic "*-isliją" [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-else#Old_English).

Comment: A cognate to the English "dam-sel"?

Comment: @Dan apparently not, following the links from [mademoiselle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mademoiselle) we see PGem \*-ilaz > Ger *-el*, with e.g. [*Schlüssel, Flügel, Wimpel, Wurzel, En. barrel*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Proto-Germanic_words_suffixed_with_*-ilaz), though the etymology is apparently uncertain. Which makes me wonder how certain this answer really is.

Comment: @vectory But have also Mitbringsel < mitbringen, Anhängsel <- anhängen etc., so -sel is still productive.

Comment: Also: Bändsel; Brösel seems to fit, but apparently has had its -s- since PIE (mhd. dim. _brosemlin_ < mhd. _brosem(e) < ahd. _bros(a)ma_, related to nhd. Brosame).

Comment: @phipsgabler Note that the words formed with the suffix -sel are usually constructed quite transparently from a verb (mitbringen -> Mitbringsel, streuen -> Streusel, raten -> Rätsel, stoppen (Low German, corresponding to High German "stopfen") -> Stöpsel. One should not assume that *every* occurrence of "sel" can be traced back to the suffix -sel. In fact, in many cases, the "s" belongs to the root, rather than to a suffix.

Comment: And Esel relates to…? (SCNR, just kidding.)

Comment: @vectory Vulgar Latin diminutive. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/damsel
No reason for it not to be present in German as well.

Comment: @Uwe that was actually what I was trying to hint at: Brösel came to my mind, but then I remembered Brosame, which made me doubt its origin, and I looked it up.